# How to bind a DataTemplate datatype to a View which receives ViewModels a dependency injected by DI

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, dependency-injection, datatemplate

I have a WPF application which implements navigation using MVVM, filling a different `DataTemplate` for each View within the same `Window` e.g. :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type foo:FooViewModel}">
        <foo:FooView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type bar:BarViewModel}">
        <bar:BarView/>
    </DataTemplate>
<Window.Resources>
```

([Switching between Views/UserControls using MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) is Rachel Lim's article which has inspired the aforementioned approach)

What happens now is that FooView gets FooViewModel automatically injected as a dependency by DI (which in my case is *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection* on .Net Core3 Preview) e.g. :

```
public partial class FooView : UserControl
{
    public FooView(FooViewModel fooViewModel)
    {  
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = fooViewModel;
    }
}
```

At this point obviously the DataTemplate complains because the FooView does not define a parameter-less ctor (as per reference [Type '{0}' is not usable as an object element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/bb546933(v=vs.90)))

Is there any way to bypass this issue and let FooView to use FooViewModel as DataContext?

Comment: Do you need this dependency injection at all? The element(s) in a DataTemplate are not supposed to explicitly set their own DataContext. It will instead automatically be set, e.g. to the Content value of a ContentControl that uses the DataTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens You're perfectly right. As ASh pointed out I completely missed this point and I was under the impression that the View had to define its own DataContext. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type foo:FooViewModel}">
    <foo:FooView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

will assign an instance of FooViewModel to FooView.DataContext.

`this.DataContext = fooViewModel;` line in `FooView` control is useless, because DataContext will be overwritten in such scenario. I would say, it is perfectly fine *not* to pass view model via contrustor. It can be accessed from DataContext:

```
public partial class FooView : UserControl
{
    public FooView()
    {  
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private FooViewModel Vm { get { return this.DataContext as FooViewModel; } }
}
```

In the navigation pattern you are using, View is a receiver of ViewModel. Current ViewModel is set by `AppViewModel`:

```
public class AppViewModel
{
    // simplified properties
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel {get; set;}
    public ICommand ViewFooCommand {get;}
    public ICommand ViewBarCommand {get;}
}
```

You are trying to make View an originator/producer of ViewModel, which conflicts with pattern.

Comment: Thank you @ASh that worked. I was actually missing this point you mentioned `this.DataContext = fooViewModel; line in FooView control is useless`.